# Rename *.csv.* files with mutilple extensions in Linux bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I would like to rename files with multiple extensions (only the csv files) with .csv extension to the end.

### example Input files in directory:

zebra.txt
sounds.pdf
input.csv
input.csv.aa
input.csv.ab   ..   ..
input.csv.zz
123.csv
123.csv.aa   ...
123.csc.zz   xxx.csv   yyy.csv

All *.csv.* files are in the same format. I would like the output to be *.csv file with no further extensions

I would like to rename the files to keep the last part of extension to be swapped like below.

input.csv.aa to input_aa.csv
input.csv.ab to input_ab.csv   ..
input.csv.zz to input_zz.csv
xxx.csv - will remain as is
yyy.csv - will remain as is

or

2. If we can combine to one file based on name, that is fine too

input.csv (combined all input.csv.aa,input.csv.ab, ..,input.csv.zz)
123.csv (combined all 123.csv.aa, .. , 123.csc.zz)   xxx.csv   yyy.csv

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for your first option:

```
find . -name "*.csv*" | \
  sed -e 's/\(\(.*\)\.csv\(.*\)\)/\1|\2\3.csv/' | \
  tr '|' '\n' | \
  xargs -n 2 mv
```

This does:

1. Finds all the files with a `.csv` extension somewhere in the name, putting one filename per line
2. Changes the line to output the original name, then a pipe character (`|`), then a new filename with any additional extensions after `.csv` moved to come before the `.csv` (e.g. `input.csv.aa` becomes `input.csv.aa|input.aa.csv`)
3. Replace pipe with a newline
4. For every two lines, pass as arguments to `mv` to rename the files

Answer (score 0):

To rename `*.csv` files:

```
find . -regex ".*\.csv\.[a-z]*$" -exec rename 's/(\.csv)\.([a-z]+)$/_$2$1/' {} \;
```

- `-regex pattern` - file name matches regular expression `pattern`
- `rename perlexp` - renames the filenames according to the Perl expression `perlexp`

---

To combine a *separate* group of files (let's say `input.csv.aa,input.csv.ab, ..,input.csv.zz`) into one file - use the following `cat` approach:

```
cat input.csv.* > input.csv
```